# Search or search for

Tags: verbs

Is there a difference? How to write correctly?

> "They searched my car"

and

> 'They searched *for* my car'

Comment: ***Search*** can be used intransitively *(**We searched,** but we couldn't find him),* or transitively *(**We searched his car,** but we couldn't find any drugs).* If a direct object with no preposition is specified, it will identify *where* the search was made - if you want to refer to *the thing sought*, it must be introduced using ***for***. Note that the "location" can be preceded by prepositions/adverbs, as in *We searched **in** the garden, **around** the house, **under** the bed,* etc. (but there's a difference between, say, *We searched the bed* and *We searched under the bed*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should write an answer. While the accepted answer is correct, your comment details the grammar rules behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They searched my car" = they searched inside my car

"They searched for my car" = they searched in order to try and find where my car was